# GUI C++ - Paint multiple lines? (Beginner question)

Tags: c++, user-interface, paint, textout

I want to explore C++ GUI coding.

I downloaded the example below and wanted to modify the output highlighted with: "<---------------". I know its a very stupid question but my goal is to learn the concept of GUI with C++ by doing.

What and why I have to do in order to add the second line "Test. 3, 2, 1.". My approach didn't work and only results the first line.

```
// HelloWindowsDesktop.cpp
// compile with: /D_UNICODE /DUNICODE /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /c

#include <windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <tchar.h>

// Global variables

// The main window class name.
static TCHAR szWindowClass[] = _T("DesktopApp");

// The string that appears in the application's title bar.
static TCHAR szTitle[] = _T("Test Title");

HINSTANCE hInst;

// Forward declarations of functions included in this code module:
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

int CALLBACK WinMain(
    _In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
    _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    _In_ LPSTR     lpCmdLine,
    _In_ int       nCmdShow
)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wcex;

    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wcex.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wcex.hInstance = hInstance;
    wcex.hIcon = LoadIcon(hInstance, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wcex.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
    wcex.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wcex.lpszClassName = szWindowClass;
    wcex.hIconSm = LoadIcon(wcex.hInstance, IDI_APPLICATION);

    if (!RegisterClassEx(&wcex))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL,
            _T("Call to RegisterClassEx failed!"),
            _T("Test Program 00"),
            NULL);

        return 1;
    }

    // Store instance handle in our global variable
    hInst = hInstance;

    // The parameters to CreateWindow explained:
    // szWindowClass: the name of the application
    // szTitle: the text that appears in the title bar
    // WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW: the type of window to create
    // CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT: initial position (x, y)
    // 500, 100: initial size (width, length)
    // NULL: the parent of this window
    // NULL: this application does not have a menu bar
    // hInstance: the first parameter from WinMain
    // NULL: not used in this application
    HWND hWnd = CreateWindow(
        szWindowClass,
        szTitle,
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
        500, 100,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        hInstance,
        NULL
    );

    if (!hWnd)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL,
            _T("Call to CreateWindow failed!"),
            _T("Test Program 01"),
            NULL);

        return 1;
    }

    // The parameters to ShowWindow explained:
    // hWnd: the value returned from CreateWindow
    // nCmdShow: the fourth parameter from WinMain
    ShowWindow(hWnd,
        nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);

    // Main message loop:
    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return (int)msg.wParam;
}

//  FUNCTION: WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM)
//
//  PURPOSE:  Processes messages for the main window.
//
//  WM_PAINT    - Paint the main window
//  WM_DESTROY  - post a quit message and return
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc;
    TCHAR greeting[] = _T("Test. 1, 2, 3.");
    PAINTSTRUCT ps1;
    HDC hdc1;
    TCHAR greeting1[] = _T("Test. 3, 2, 1.");

    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_PAINT:
        hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        

        // Here your application is laid out.
        // For this introduction, we just print out "Hello, Windows desktop!" <-----------------------------------------------
        // in the top left corner.
        TextOut(hdc,
            5, 5,
            greeting, _tcslen(greeting));
        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);


        // CAN ONLY PAINT ONE???
        hdc1 = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps1);
        TextOut(hdc1,
            6, 6,
            greeting1, _tcslen(greeting1));

        // End application-specific layout section.
        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps1);


        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
        break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[image: I added greeting1]

Comment: Don't call `BeginPaint` the second time. Just add the `TextOut` call. Note also that the coordinates (the second and third parameter) are in pixels: you are painting the second line almost exactly over the first one. Give it some space.

Comment: Thanks, that solved it!